# Problem with timezone in Django ORM, datetime value differs from the value stored in the table

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

I have stored some data into PostgreSQL database. Here is the corresponding Django model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class PrecipitationContourDjango10d(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    geometry = models.PolygonField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    window_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.date < other.date:
            return True
        return False

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'precipitation_contour_web_service10d'
```

Here is some rows that are stored in the table:
[image]

As you can see the datetime value for the row with **id**=5921 is **2021-05-07 21:00:00-07**.
However when I retrieve that row using the Django ORM, its datetime field will change:

```
from data.models import PrecipitationContourDjango10d
row = PrecipitationContourDjango10d.objects.get(id=5921)
```

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of ```row.date```?

Comment: **print(row.date)** prints: 2021-05-07 23:00:00

Comment: row.date should be a datetime object. What about `row.date.tzinfo` ?

Comment: **print(row.date.tzinfo)** prints None

Comment: Did you set USE_TZ to false?

Comment: @Melvyn, yes. But still getting the same inconsistent result.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an issue. This is how things work when `USE_TZ` is False:

- Your Postgres has timezone set to UTC-7 (for example US/Pacific), either through config or machine time, and this is what your client is showing
- Your Django has timezone set to UTC-5 (for example US/Central), either through config or machine time and datetimes are translated to naive datetimes in Django's timezone

If working with timezones is important to you, you should read the [topic in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/) carefully and enable USE_TZ:

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.
>
> This is handy if your users live in more than one time zone and you want to display datetime information according to each user’s wall clock.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this valuable link. This is working. I will post a complete answer ASAP

Answer (score 0):

You must be aware that the second result you provided does not mention any timezone. It may have an hidden timezone based on your system preference. This does not mean they are different.

For instance : '2021-05-07 21:00:00-07' and '2021-05-07 23:00:00-05' actually are the same datetimes, expressed in two different timezones (i.e the same moments but expressed in the local time of two different places in the world).

EDIT : Set `USE_TZ=True` in django config file for a consistent use of timezone aware datetime (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/).

Comment: So, how should I change the settings so that they refer to the same timezone and eventually to the same values?

Comment: I am not familiar with your developing tools (especially if you are using an IDE to check values in objects which may not behave the same as plain python code). I would suggest you to first check what is the value of the datetime (with timezone) you want to insert (python code) and check if it is coherent with the plain value stored in postgresql database (do not hesitate to run `psql <my_database_name>` and then a plein SQL request `SELECT * FROM <precipitation_contour_django_10_d_table> WHERE <table>.id = <id_of_inserted_element>` and check that the datetime value in database corresponds.

Comment: I examined the datetime objects that I was sending into the database. They were the same as what is stored in the database. So, my guess is that Django ORM gets the data from the database incorrectly.

Comment: So actually the point is that Django is not using timezones. Please set USE_TZ to True in your django config file. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: EDIT : This solution was mentionned just before my comment in another answer.